# C# Timer to consider callback time

Tags: c#, timer

I would like to have a timer which its interval considering the callback invokation time.

For example, If timer interval is 1000ms, callback invokation takes roughly 500ms,
then t0 = 0, t1 = 1500, t2 = 3000.

Obviously I dont want to store the invokation time (or its average) in a field, I want it to work as perfect as it can.

I kind of solved it but it just looks bad.

```
System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
timer.Elapsed += (sender, args) =>
{
    timer.Stop();
    Console.WriteLine(args.SignalTime);
    Thread.Sleep(500); //instead!!!, there is something with Db and logistics.. no really a thread sleep

    timer.Start();
};

timer.Start();
```

Is it the only solution or is there any built-in feature in C# already?

Comment: That looks totally equal to running `Thread` with `Sleep(1000);` at the end.

Comment: ignore the thread sleep in the invokation please.
Thread.sleep isnt releasing the thread from the thread pool while timer disposes the thread..

Comment: I think what @Sinatr means is that what you want is equivalent to running the method, followed with a sleep of 1 second in a separate thread in a loop. You don't need a timer for this.

Comment: @PeterBons but why? Timer isn't locking a thread while waiting between operations. Thread.Sleep does.

Comment: Then use Task.Delay...Look, we are laying out some options. If you don't want to modify the timer in the callback method you obviously need something else.

Answer (score 4):

You can use a `System.Threading.Timer` with a dueTime of 1000 and an infinite period:

```
using System.Threading;

Timer timer = new Timer(callback, null, 1000, Timeout.Infinite);
```

Then at the end of you callback method, call `timer.Change(1000, Timeout.Infinite)`, which will cause your callback to be called 1000 ms after it has finished, regardless of how long your callback takes to execute.

Comment: so it basically the same thing.. I need to modify Timer within the callback.. its what im trying to avoid.
I could just wrap it in an external class, which is something I dont want to do..

Comment: This is a very common way to use a timer. As far as I know, .NET doesn't provide a timer that does this for you.